# String length - incorrect result?

Tags: java, string

I can't understand what is wrong with the following code:

```
System.out.println("TEST:"+"/index/index/(\\d+)/".length());
```

Output: TEST:19 . But as I see there must be 20. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Don't count escape chars Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In java, `\` is an escape character.

So: The `\\` is actually a single `\`.

And therefore that part of the string reads like this: `(\d+)`, which as per regex definition means "1 or more digits" :)

Comment: Than I don't understand why I can't use in regex \d+ instead of \\d+. Could your explain?

Comment: Because with `\d` the escape character "escapes" with the d, which is actually undefined, but if it was `\t` or `\n` then it would escape to mean something. In your case, you require an "actual" slash in your regular expression, therefore \\ gives you that. Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Comment: @PashaTurok ``\`` is special character in String. It can be used to create line separators like `\n` `\r` or tabulator `\t` or to escape `"` (if we write `\"` inside string this double quote mark will not represent end of string but just literal) or `\uXXXX` where `XXXX` part is hex for Unicode index of character you want to print. So since ``\`` is special we can't just write `\d` because compiler will try to interpret it as something special. So to create ``\`` literal we need to escape it with another ``\`` which means that string representing one ``\`` needs to be written as `"\\"`.

Comment: @Pshemo Thank you for detailed answer. For my web application I use regex for Urlpattern - some class that keeps some pattern. Firstly I created this class instances by code new UrlPatter("/index/index/(\\d+)/"). Everything was ok. Then I put all patterns in xml file and via Apache Digester create urlpatterns automatically. And what I observed - pattern from xml works ONLY IF in xml I put the following <pattern regex="/index/index/(\d+)/" />. Notice that in xml I use "(\d+)". How can it be explained?

Comment: @Pshemo I mean that now something like this = new UrlPattern(attibutes.getValue("regex"));

Comment: @Pshemo - am I right this is because java compiler merges in strings \\ to \ so from xml we must put "\"?

Comment: @PashaTurok Yes, compiler only treats ``\`` as special character if it is placed in string literal ``\`` (like `String str = "here is where \\ is special";`). If you lets say read text from outside then characters are treated literally (if text will contain `\n` it will be read as ``\`` and `n` characters) so you don't need to escape them with ``\``.